# How to pass ArrayList< com.google.api.services.drive.model.File> to Activity

Tags: android, arraylist, android-activity, google-drive-api

I know that if I want to pass something custom it has to implement Serializable, or even Parcelable. but in this case, I am not sure how to pass a list of Files ( from the google drive api) to an activity.

Answer (score 0):

If `File` implements `Serializable` I would try this.

```
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putSerializable("your_key_for_this_object", mFileObjectArrayList);
    intent.putExtras(args);
    startActivity(intent);
```

If `File` implements `Parcelable` I would try this.

```
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putParcelableArrayList("your_key_for_this_object", mFileObjectArrayList);
    intent.putExtras(args);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Then in the `Activity` that is receiving the `Bundle`, try something like this.

```
    Bundle args = getIntent().getExtras();
    mFileObjectArrayList = (ArrayList<File>) args.getSerializable("your_key_for_this_object");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I dont think File from the google drive service implements either of those..

Thank you for the input though.

Comment: @Vnge, did you end up making `com.google.api.services.drive.model.File` parcelable?